# Hide div with jquery inside an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

With AJAX I'm trying to replace the text "`Follow`" with a spinner and then display the success message.

The html code inside a loop looks like this:

```
<div id="author-id-3" class="km-follow-me">                         
    <div class="km-author-follow">
        <a id="3" class="km-meta-badge">Follow</a>
    </div>          
</div>
```

AJAX call

```
jQuery('.km-author-follow').on('click', '.km-meta-badge', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();

  var $container = $(this).closest('.km-follow-me');

  $.ajax( {       
    ...     
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(this).closest('.km-follow-me km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
      $( '<div class="icon-loading"></div>' ).hide().appendTo( $container ).fadeIn( 'slow' );     
    },
    success: function( data ) {
      $container.find('.icon-loading').remove();
      $container.html(data).hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );

    },    

  } )
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that inside the `beforeSend function`, the text "`Follow`" doesn't get hidden. The spinner does show up, as does the success message.

Neither

```
$(this).closest('.km-follow-me').find('.km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
```

nor

```
$(this).closest('.km-follow-me km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
```

is working.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is `this` referring to?  Is the code running inside of a binding?

Comment: ah, that should be `jQuery('.km-author-follow').on('click', '.km-meta-badge', function(e) { ... }`

Comment: I don't see any class `'.km-meta-badge'`, which is what you're binding to.

Comment: Ah, that's a typo here. It should be `km-meta-badge` instead.

Comment: Missing a `.` in front of second class in `$(this).closest('.km-follow-me km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );`

Comment: Even with the additional `dot` (^^;;;) the text is still not faded out.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this.

```
<div id="author-id-3" class="km-follow-me">                         
    <div id="spinner" style="display:none"><img src="/path/to/spinner" /></div>
    <div class="km-author-follow">
        <a id="3" class="meta-badge">Follow</a>
    </div>          
</div>
```

with the following:

```
jQuery('.km-author-follow').on('click', '.km-meta-badge', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    let spinner    = document.getElementById("spinner");

    spinner.style.display = 'block';
    let container        = $(this).closest('.km-follow-me');
    container.style.display = 'none';

    $.ajax({       
        // .. do ajax call
    }).done(function(return) {
        spinner.style.display = 'none';
        container.style.display = 'block';
    })
});
```

Granted, I left out the animation you wanted, but this illustrates the easier way to do it.

Just hide / reveal the two different divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $container = $(this).closest('.km-follow-me');
```

Ended up using

```
$container.find('.km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
```

instead which works.

I don't know why

```
$(this).closest('.km-follow-me').find('.km-author-follow').fadeOut( 'fast' );
```

isn't working while the first one is. Aren't they pretty much the same?